# Using equivalence properties show that $[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (p \land (\neg q))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I almost have the answer but I can't seem to figure out how to make the last contradiction disappear.

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (p \land (\neg q))$

---

(i) Commutativity and Associativity

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (\neg q) \land (p \land p) \land ((\neg q)\lor q) \land (\neg r)$

(ii) Idempotence and Contradiction

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (\neg q) \land p \land$ **0** $\land (\neg r)$

(iii) Commutativity and De Morgan's Laws

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (p \land (\neg q)) \land (\neg((\neg$ **0** $)\lor r))$

(iv) Tautology

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (p \land (\neg q)) \land (\neg($ **1** $\lor r))$

(v) Tautology

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (p \land (\neg q)) \land (\neg($ **1** $))$

(vi) Contradiction

$[(p\land (\neg q)) \land (p\land (\neg q)) \lor (q\land (\neg r))] \iff (p \land (\neg q)) \land$ **0**

Note: **1** means tautology and **0** means contradiction

Comment: You should mention what operation you're doing on each step.

Comment: $(i) \quad\lnot q \lor q \equiv 1$, not $0$. $\lnot q \land q \equiv 0$. So you're off to a problematic start.

Comment: In $i$, $(p \land \lnot q) \land (p \land \lnot q) \equiv p \land \lnot q$

Comment: @amWhy thank you for pointing that out to me. I made changes accordingly and posted the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t follow your first step; it certainly doesn’t follow just from associativity and commutativity. Your $\big((\neg q)\lor q\big)$ suggests that you’ve tried to use distributivity, but in that case you should also have $(\neg q)\lor(\neg r)$, among other things. In any case, the expression on the right-hand side after your step (i) is true only when $r$ is false, which is not the case for the target expression $p\land(\neg q)$, so you can’t possibly reduce yours to the desired target.

You have

$$\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\land\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\lor\big(q\land(\neg r)\big)\;.$$

If $\varphi\equiv p\land(\neg q)$ and $\psi\equiv q\land(\neg r)$, this is $\varphi\land\varphi\lor\psi$. Unfortunately, this is ambiguous unless you have a convention giving one of the connectives precedence over the other. If it means $(\varphi\land\varphi)\lor\psi$, then it reduces to $\varphi\lor\psi$, which is $\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\lor\big(q\land(\neg r)\big)$, which you can then expand using distributivity to

$$\Big(\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\lor q\Big)\land\Big(\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\lor(\neg r)\Big)\;,$$

thence to

$$(p\lor q)\land\big((\neg q)\lor q\big)\land\big(p\lor(\neg r)\big)\land\big((\neg q)\lor(\neg r)\big)\;,$$

and, after reducing $(\neg q)\lor q$ to $1$, to

$$(p\lor q)\land\big(p\lor(\neg r)\big)\land\big((\neg q)\lor(\neg r)\big)\;.\tag{1}$$

It’s not hard to check that if $r$ is false, $q$ is true, and $p$ is false, then $(1)$ is true but $p\land(\neg q)$ is false, so the two can’t be equivalent.

If $\varphi\land\varphi\lor\psi$ means $\varphi\land(\varphi\lor\psi)$, on the other hand, you can use an absorption law to reduce it to $\varphi$, which is exactly what you want. I suspect, therefore, that you’re missing a parenthesis, and that the left-hand side should be

$$\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\land\Big(\big(p\land(\neg q)\big)\lor\big(q\land(\neg r)\big)\Big)\;.$$

Comment: I probably should have broken that step down a bit. I first used Commutativity to make $(p \land \neg q)$ into $(\neg q \land p)$. Then I used Associativity to remove the original parentheses and regrouped so that I could reduce $(p \land p)$ to $p$ and $(\neg q \lor q)$ to a contradiction(**0**)

Comment: @cunicorn: There is no legitimate way to remove the parentheses to get $\neg q\lor q$.

Comment: If I'm splitting the second $(p \land \neg q)$ so that I can get $((\neg q \land p) \land p)$ then why can't I take the leftover $\neg q$ and repeat the process going from ...$(\neg q \lor (q \land \neg r)$ to ...$((\neg q \lor q) \land \neg r$ ?

Comment: @cunicorn: Because you have different operators: $\land$ is associative, so $p\land(q\land r)\equiv(p\land q)\land r$, and $\lor$ is associative, so $p\lor(q\lor r)\equiv(p\lor q)\lor r$, but you have a mixed expression of the form $p\lor(q\land r)$. Associativity doesn’t hold for such expressions; what you have for them is distributivity: $$p\lor(q\land r)\equiv(p\lor q)\land(p\lor r)\;.$$

Comment: Oh okay. Thanks for bringing that to my attention and sorry for giving you a hard time about it!

Comment: @cunicorn: You’re welcome; no problem!